# How to withdraw a contracts funds?

Tags: contract-development, remix

How can an address withdraw a contract's ether?

```
contract MyContract {
  address payable public withdrawAddress = 0x........; 

  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function totalBalance() external view returns(uint) {
    return address(owner).balance;
  }

  function withdrawFunds() external withdrawAddressOnly() {
    msg.sender.transfer(this.totalBalance());
  }

  modifier withdrawAddressOnly() {
    require(msg.sender == withdrawAddress, 'only withdrawer can call this');
   _;
  }

  ...
}
```

I'm calling `withdrawFunds()` from the "withdrawAddress" address, but I'm getting the following error:

`transact to MyContract.withdrawFunds errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.`

I'm not setting the `withdrawFunds` as payable, because I'm not sending that function any funds to handle, the contract ***already has the funds***. My intention is to transfer all the contracts' Ether to an address.

Here is a link to the code
https://github.com/norris-labs/EthText/blob/main/EthText.sol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that the function to retrieve the total balance doesn't seem to be correct: it is retrieving the owner's balance, but not the contract's balance.

I changed the constructor as payable and created the smart contract by including 1 ether during the creation, defining the owner variable (missing) and updating the `totalBalance()` function:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.12;

contract Test {

   address payable public withdrawAddress = 0xb5....;
   address public owner;

   constructor() public payable {
     owner = msg.sender;
   }

   function totalBalance() external view returns(uint) {
     //return address(owner).balance;
     return payable(address(this)).balance;
   }

   function withdrawFunds() external withdrawAddressOnly() {
     msg.sender.transfer(this.totalBalance());
   }

   modifier withdrawAddressOnly() {
     require(msg.sender == withdrawAddress, 'only withdrawer can call this');
   _;
   }
}
```

It is now working as expected and transferring the contract's balance to the designated `withdrawAddress`.

By the way, instead of declaring the constructor as payable (just for quick testing), I assume you might be using a specific function to receive ethers within the contract.